# Delete column if range is blank

Tags: vba, range, delete-row

I am looking to find guidance on building a macro to delete columns depending if the range is empty. I am having trouble defining my range so it changes with every loop, i'm new to VBA so information on setting up this range would be helpful for this code and building code in the future!

```
Sub sbDelete_Columns_IF_Cell_Is_empty()
Dim lColumn As Long
Dim iCntr As Long
lColumn = 103
For iCntr = lColumn To 1 Step -1
    If IsEmpty(Range()
        Columns(iCntr).Delete
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

second attempt, this is being weird and deleting columns that i don't want it to delete

```
Sub sbDelete_Columns_IF_Cell_Is_Blank()
Dim lColumn As Long
Dim iCntr As Long
Dim i As Integer
Dim f As Integer
i = 4
f = 100

lColumn = 103
For iCntr = lColumn To 1 Step -1
    If IsEmpty(Range(Cells(f, i), (Cells(f, i)))) = True Then
        Columns(iCntr).Delete
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you want to delete it if a whole column is blank or just one cell?

Comment: no i am looking to delete a column if range of cells is blank the column, the columns have headers and another row of a data so i want to select start at a specific row (4)  to the end row

Comment: 1)You can't do what you want with `isempty` 2) your `Cells()` references are wrong.  Study the answer I gave you, particularly the `IF` statement and how I did the `Cells()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
Sub sbDelete_Columns_IF_Cell_Is_empty()
Dim lColumn As Long
Dim iCntr As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rwsToCheck As Long

Set ws = ActiveSheet
rwsToCheck = 1000 'Change to what ever you want
lColumn = 103
For iCntr = lColumn To 1 Step -1
    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(ws.Range(ws.Cells(4, iCntr), ws.Cells(rwsToCheck, iCntr))) = 0 Then
        ws.Columns(iCntr).Delete
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: kablam! this works, i'm going to put my second attempt up in an edit, can you tell me what's wrong with it? i'm going forward with your macro but want to see what i'm doing wrong with mine and the differences in process from yours